# Finding the order of $(1, 1) + \langle(2, 2)\rangle$ in the factor group $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / \langle (2, 2)\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

I read somewhere that the order of $(1, 1) + \langle(2, 2)\rangle$ in the factor group $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / \langle (2, 2)\rangle$ is $2$. I am trying to understand how this is true. I have:

$(1, 1) + (-2, -2) = (-1, -1) \neq (0, 0)$

$(1, 1) + (0, 0) = (1, 1)$

$(1, 1) + (2, 2) = (3, 3)$

$(1, 1) + (4, 4) = (5, 5)$

$(1, 1) + (6, 6) = (7, 7) \neq (0, 0)$

How is the order of $(1, 1) + \langle(2, 2)\rangle$ in the factor group $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / \langle (2, 2)\rangle$ equal to $2$?

Comment: Because $(1,1)+(1,1)=(0,0)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner If I understand your comment correctly, I think you're choosing $(1, 1)$ as a representative of the coset $(1, 1) + \langle (2, 2) \rangle$. So, to compute $(1, 1) + \langle (2, 2) \rangle + (1, 1) + \langle (2, 2) \rangle$, you compute $(1, 1) + (1, 1)$. But, isn't $(1, 1) + (1, 1) = (2, 2) \neq (0, 0)$? where $(0, 0)$ is the identity of the factor group. Is $(2, 2)$ the identity of the factor group?

Comment: You are correct I should have written $(1,1)+\langle(2,2)\rangle+(1,1)+\langle(2,2)\rangle=(0,0)+\langle(2,2)\rangle$, because $(0,0)+\langle2,2\rangle=(2,2)+\langle(2,2)\rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good typesetting, by the way!

The calculations you are doing are finding *elements* of the coset $(1, 1) + \langle(2, 2)\rangle$; but that's not what you're asking.

The *order* of the coset $(1, 1) + \langle(2, 2)\rangle$ (that is, its order in the factor group $(\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z)/\langle(2, 2)\rangle$) is the smallest positive integer $m$ such that $m$ times $(1, 1) + \langle(2, 2)\rangle$ is equal to the identity element of $(\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z)/\langle(2, 2)\rangle$.

So to answer this question, you'll need to be able to answer these sub-questions:

- What is the identity element of $(\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z)/\langle(2, 2)\rangle$?
- How can you tell in general whether $(a, b) + \langle(2, 2)\rangle$ is equal to this identity element?
- What is the definition of "$m$ times $(1, 1) + \langle(2, 2)\rangle$"?
- Is $1\times\big( (1, 1) + \langle(2, 2)\rangle \big)$ equal to the identity element of $(\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z)/\langle(2, 2)\rangle$? Is $2\times\big( (1, 1) + \langle(2, 2)\rangle \big)$ equal to this identity element? Is $3\times\big( (1, 1) + \langle(2, 2)\rangle \big)$ equal to this identity element? ...

Answer (score 0):

The order of an element $a$ of a group is the smallest positive integer $m$

such that $\underbrace{a+a+\cdot+a}_{m\text{ times}}$ is the identity element of the group.

The order of $(1,1)$ in the quotient group $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/\langle(2,2)\rangle$ is $2$,

because $(1,1)\not\in \langle(2,2)\rangle$, but $(1,1)+(1,1)=(2,2)\in\langle(2,2)\rangle$;

$(0,0)$ and $(2,2)$ are both in the same coset of $\langle(2,2)\rangle$,

which is $\langle(2,2)\rangle$, the identity element of the quotient group.

Answer (score 0):

$\langle(2,2)\rangle=\{(2,2)^i,i\in \mathbb{Z}\}=\{(2i,2i),i\in \mathbb{Z}\}$

$(1,1)+\langle(2,2)\rangle=\{(1+2i,1+2i),i\in \mathbb{Z}\}$

\begin{alignat}{1}
\bigl((1,1)+\langle(2,2)\rangle\bigr)^2 &= \{(2+2i+2j,2+2i+2j),i,j\in \mathbb{Z}\} \\
&= \{(2(1+i+j),2(1+i+j)),i,j\in \mathbb{Z}\} \\
&= \{(2k,2k),k\in \mathbb{Z}\} \\
&= \langle(2,2)\rangle \\
\tag 1
\end{alignat}